# Sci-fi movie with highly intelligent humans, the higher ones being very old

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

Around 6 year ago, I watched a sci-fi movie that I would like to watch again. But... Sadly I do not have much to go on.

All I can remember is there was this group of highly intelligent humans (possible living in space) that looked after and breed humans to extend their own life...

I can remember one of the higher beings, being very old like 200 years old etc... and can remember some group of people finding out about what they were doing.

The movie was not vampire- or AI-related.

Comment: Hi there! :) That's already some info, but maybe you could take a look at [this guide on how to ask a good story-id question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any memories you could[edit] in? For instance, did you watch it in English, was it a translation? Was the movie rather new? Did you watch it at a theater or on TV - if so, any idea which channel it could have ired on? Stuff like that, to increase the chances of a successful identification. Cheers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can think of two movies this might be so you're getting two answers the second is:

*[Jupiter Ascending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter_Ascending)*, in which non-Earthbound humans use humanity as a raw material to make an immortality serum. Worlds, including Earth are used as breeding grounds for crops of humans whose essence is then extracted to allow others to live forever, as long as they can afford it. I think this may be the more likely from description but it may be too recent.

Comment: I have just seen the trailer.. and that is the one... Many kind thanks!!

Comment: @True Happy to help.

Comment: I think this movie was just panned and I recall not liking it. It amazes me how bad even big-budget scifi can be. I suspect the writer has a vision too ambitious or detailed to make it to the screen -- this is why there will always be books, a superior storytelling technology for some stories anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two movies this might be so you're getting two answers the first is:

*[Æon Flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86on_Flux_(film))*, in which the human race has been reduced to one last Earthly city. The population is continually cloned to maintain the last of the human race by two or maybe three serially immortal individuals (I can't remember quite where/how Pete Postlethwaite's character fits in) who keep watch over everything.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but I have now found it!!